# Memory allocation error for 2D pointer in class in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, typedef

Allocating memory for the two-dimensional pointer in the class I want to do. But the intellisense of the IDE I use is giving me this errors. I use VSCode as IDE.

```
 a value of type "OutClass::InClass **" cannot be assigned to an entity of type  "OutClass::InClass **"

 a value of type "OutClass::InClass *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "OutClass::InClass *"
```

It shows the assignment operator errors on the line where I use the new operator. But the errors disappear when you write the code with typedef declarations as in the code. I have two questions.

1. My first question is, Is there an error or undefined behavior in the
   code I write this way ? Or is it VSCode's problem ?
2. My second question is, how do these typedef declarations destroy
   the error ? (and is it useful to use these typedef declarations
   in this    way ?)

```
#include <iostream>

//typedef OutClass::InClass* firstDef; 
//typedef OutClass::InClass  secDef;

class OutClass { 
public:
    class InClass {
        public:
            InClass() = default;
        private:
            int a;
    };
    OutClass(); 
private:
    int size;
    InClass **inptr; };

OutClass::OutClass() {
    std::cout << "Please enter size:\n";
    std::cin  >> this->size;

    inptr = new InClass*[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        inptr[i] = new InClass[size];
    } 
/*
    inptr = new firstDef[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        inptr[i] = new secDef[size];
    }
*/ 
}
```

Comment: Is the error you show us the *full* and *complete* error output you get? There's really nothing else in the output when you build? Also please [edit] your question to add comments in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code. Intellisense isn't perfect though. It often makes mistakes that the compiler won't do. Btw, why use an array of pointers like that? `std::vector<InClass> inptr;` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, full and complete error. It just writes C/C++(513) at the end of the error. Just because that is what makes me think the possibility of intellisense being inaccurate.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I absolutely agree with you. But I use pointers due to the requirements of my project.

Comment: So it's *only* the "IntelliSense" that's giving you problem? It works when you actually build the code?

Comment: @stnbl If some other part of the project requires pointers, you can supply pointers to the elements in the vector. Or is it a school project and you are required to use pointers for the sake of learning?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, the GCC compiler does not give an error or warning. Funny thing is, the mistake of IntelliSense sometimes comes and goes.

Comment: Side notes: Don't forget the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and consider improving the cache friendliness with one one big array of `size*size` instead of having `size+1` different arrays.

Comment: @stnbl Then forget about the IntelliSense errors.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Exactly as you said. Sad but true :( The only thing that scares me is whether it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Near as I can tell, this is intellisense raising a false positive.

Comment: It's not UB (yet), but read what @user4581301 said. When dealing with raw pointers, you need to take care so reading about the rule of 3/5/0 is a must.

Comment: The parser used for Microsoft IntelliSense is known to give false positives (report false error) sometimes. It even happens when using the full Visual Studio building C++ projects with Microsofts own C++ compiler (which uses a different parser than IntelliSense).

Comment: Understood. I will review your post. Thank you so much. I guess sometimes intellisense can make our job difficult.@user4581301